# nginx crashes on ssl after about a minute

Tags: nginx, ssl, 504

Here are my configuration files

ssl.conf

```
# HTTPS server
#
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  api.domain.com;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/api.error.log;

    location / {
    root /var/www/api.domain.com;
    index index.html index.php index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/api.domain.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/api.domain.com.key;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        # root  html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/api.domain.com$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

}
```

nginx.conf

```
user              nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

I have a server running on port 80 that runs with no issues. As soon as I turn on this api server running on ssl, it works for about a minute and then crashes and gives a 504 Gateway Time-out.

Running nginx/1.2.3

Comment: What are you using for `fastcgi` and what do those configurations look like?

Answer (score 0):

Gateway timeouts in NGiNX are usually caused by problems with fastcgi (e.g. `spawn_fcgi`, `php-fpm`).

Make sure it's running and listening.

If you're using `php-fpm`, try increasing `pm.max_children` and `pm.max_requests`.

If `pm` is set to `dynamic`, try upping the `pm.start_servers`, `pm.min_spare_servers`, and `pm.max_spare_servers`.

If you're still having issues after that, try adding shared SSL session caching and increasing your worker processes to the number of CPU cores you have in NGiNX.

Example of SSL settings:

```
    ssl on;

    ##
    # For SSL caching
    ##
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m; 

    ##
    # For chained certs
    ##
    ssl_verify_depth 4; 

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/privkey.pem;

    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    keepalive_timeout 70;
```